# Typescript Pick<> using types rather than keys

Tags: typescript, generics, interface, typing

I under stand how the pick type works in typescript. How ever I want a version of it that will pick all the strings out of an interface rather than using the keys.

```
interface Nested {
    bla: string;
    other: number;
}

interface Testing {
    bla: string;
    other: number;
    list: Array<string>;
    list2: Array<string>;
    list3: Array<any>;
    list4: Array<number>;
    objecter: Nested
    objecter2: object
}


type NewPickType<T,Type> = // Some Typescript interface Logic 

type StringArrayOnlyType = NewPickType<Testing,Array<string>>

let obj: StringArrayOnlyType = {
    bla: "", // error
    other: 0, // error
    list: [""], // ok 
    list2: [""], // ok
    list3: [""], // ok
    list4: [0], // error
    objecter: { bla: "", other: 0 }, // error
    objecter2: {} // error
}
```

Any ideas on how to build the `NewPickType`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up figuring it out just after posting but this might help some other people.

```
export type PickTypeKeys<Obj, Type, T extends keyof Obj = keyof Obj> = ({ [P in keyof Obj]: Obj[P] extends Type ? P : never })[T];

export type PickType<T, Type> = Pick<T, PickTypeKeys<T, Type>>
export type OmitType<T, Type> = Omit<T, PickTypeKeys<T, Type>>
```

Needed to use two steps on to get they keys of the type I was looking for and one to filter the object using those keys.

[Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-ndJNugXVnoJi0CvpDprDFrJFIQADkoHAxVdpaoaA0mqlpdyabzgPzBYgvqdM9my5c83J4Z8FQGWWqE-tQ+aI62GFrdfrLYxrdpbfaMY7h57vS2DcilYHFRqoyOGLGlgdSUA)